# Sort a std::list<myclass*> with myclass::operator<(myclass &other)

Tags: c++, std

I have a `std::list<myclass*>` and in my class I have `myclass::operator<(myclass &other)` defined.

I use the `std::list.sort()` function, but it does not change anything in that list. Maybe it just sorts the pointers?

How can I sort the actual items in that list?

Comment: Are you sure that `std::list` is the right container for your use case?  It is rarely a good choice; `std::vector` or `std::deque` usually provides more favorable performance characteristics.  Are you sure that you need to be storing raw pointers in the container?  That too is rarely a good choice; usually it is preferable to store your objects in the container instead of pointers to them and if you do use pointers, smart pointers should be used.

Comment: Note: If you make `operator<` a member, it should be a `const` member function. But usually it should be a non-member anyway. See [this FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are sorting the pointer values, not the myclass values. You have to write your own predicate to compare pointers by dereference:

```
template <typename T> bool PComp(const T * const & a, const T * const & b)
{
   return *a < *b;
}

std::vector<Foo*> myvec;
std::list<Foo*> mylist;
std::sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), PComp<Foo>);
mylist.sort(PComp<Foo>);
```

By the way, I think you cannot sort `std::list` with `std::sort` from `<algorithm>` because it is not random access. Use the member function `sort` instead as MerickOWA says. (But that's generally less efficient than sorting a random-access container.) Alternatively, you can immediately store your objects in a sorted container like `std::set<Foo*, PPred>`, where `PPred` is the functor version of the predicate:

```
struct PPred {
  template <typename T> inline bool operator()(const T * a, const T * b) const
  { return *a < *b; }
};
```

Comment: You can use a function instead of a struct. It's slightly less verbose.

Comment: Since you're using `const T*`, then the OP needs to define comparison as `operator<(const T &) const`.

Comment: Etienne: Perfectly right, I was thinking I'd be partially specializing something on the way, but turns out I'm not. Editing! Nawaz: Also right, editing!

Comment: What's the syntax for a "const reference to a pointer to T"? :-(

Comment: `T* const&`  There is no reason to use a reference here, though

Comment: @James: Just for giggles, since predicates are usually called by const-reference... but I would usually pass the pointer-to-const-T by copy, too :-)

Comment: @Alf: Whoops, typo! Sorry for that!

Comment: I then used mylist.sort(PComp()), but I guess it is the same.

Comment: @queueoverflow: With my current version of the example, `mylist.sort(PComp())` should not work, since `PComp` is just a function, not a class name, and since you need to specify the template paramter. Only `mylist.sort(PComp<Foo>)` should work.

Comment: This is another advantage of using a function object instead of a function:  you can lower the genericity into the `operator()` overload so that the named struct is not generic.  Instead of using `PComp<Foo>`, you can simply use `PComp()`.

Comment: @James: Good point! I added the code for the predicate again to include that aspect.

Comment: Beware the alternative! std::set is only for unique lists. You may find your sort will give you less items than you had before.

Answer (score 4):

Several answers propose using a predicate that explicitly takes two pointers; this will work for your current case where you have a container of raw pointers, but it won't work for any other dereferenceable type, like smart pointers or iterators.

Why not go the more general route and match any type?

```
struct indirect_compare
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const 
    {
        return *lhs < *rhs;
    }
}
```

While a const reference is unnecessary for a `T*`, it is necessary for smart pointer types that are relatively expensive to copy (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`) or impossible to copy (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`).

Alternatively, you might consider using something like Boost's [`indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html), which moves the indirection into the iterator and can make for much cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

It'll sort the pointer as std::sort( Container ) use the operator< defined T. Here T is myclass*, then it is sorted using comparison over pointer.

You can pass a custom comparator functor to std::sort so make one take takes two myclass* and return the proper comparison :

```
template<class T>
struct ptr_comparison
{
   bool operator()(T* a, T* b) { return *a < *b; } 
};

list<myclass*> mylist;

// later

mylist.sort(ptr_comparison<myclass>());
```

Comment: -1 for use of `std::sort` on a `std::list`. Also, the instantiantion of `ptr_comparision` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you don't have NULL pointers in your list just do

```
bool ptrsorter( myclass *a, myclass *b ) {
  return *a < *b;
  }

mylist.sort( ptrsorter );
```

or if you're lucky enough to be using a more recent compiler (with C++0x-support), you can use a lambda-expression:

```
mylist.sort( []( myclass *a, myclass *b ) { return *a < *b } );
```

Comment: `ptrsorter` should return `bool` instead of `void`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying out the template PComp example and since other classes would be using the PComp I stuck in the the include file for the class the std::list was holding.  However when I compiled the task I got this:

```
In member function ‘EcTVoid FdFtTSBFDFTableLoadAppl::IngestTableProducts(const string&, const EcTInt&)’:
/mms_builds/working/jkerich/MMS_SDF/sw/mms/dms/FdFtTSB/src/FdFtTSBFDFTableLoadAppl.C:782:53  error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list<FoFmVirtualTbl*>::sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   myIngestedTables.sort(sorter.PComp<FoFmVirtualTbl>); // sorted list
                                                     ^
/mms_builds/working/jkerich/MMS_SDF/sw/mms/dms/FdFtTSB/src/FdFtTSBFDFTableLoadAppl.C:782:53  note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/list:64:0,
                 from /mms_builds/working/jkerich/MMS_SDF/sw/mms/foscommon/common/FoCf/include/FoCfConfigSetup.h:11,
                 from /mms_builds/working/jkerich/MMS_SDF/sw/mms/foscommon/common/FoCf/include/FoCfTypes.h:156,
                 from /mms_builds/working/jkerich/MMS_SDF/sw/mms/dms/FdFtTSB/src/FdFtTSBFDFTableLoadAppl.C:18:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/list.tcc:353:5: note: void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::sort() [with _Tp = FoFmVirtualTbl*; _Alloc = std::allocator<FoFmVirtualTbl*>]
     list<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/list.tcc:353:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/list.tcc:430:7: note: void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::sort(_StrictWeakOrdering) [with _StrictWeakOrdering = bool (FoFmVirtualTbl::*)(const FoFmVirtualTbl* const&, const FoFmVirtualTbl* const&); _Tp = FoFmVirtualTbl*; _Alloc = std::allocator<FoFmVirtualTbl*>]
       list<_Tp, _Alloc>::
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/list.tcc:430:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘bool (FoFmVirtualTbl::*)(const FoFmVirtualTbl* const&, const FoFmVirtualTbl* const&)’
In file included from /ecs/MMS_SDF/RogueWave/13.2/dbg/rw/config/rwconfig_tls.h:9:0,
                 from /ecs/MMS_SDF/RogueWave/13.2/dbg/rw/compiler.h:5,
                 from /ecs/MMS_SDF/RogueWave/13.2/dbg/rw/defs.h:46,
                 from /ecs/MMS_SDF/RogueWave/13.2/dbg/rw/cstring.h:33,
                 from /mms_builds/working/jkerich/MMS_SDF/sw/mms/foscommon/common/FoCf/include/FoCfTypes.h:11,
                 from /mms_builds/working/jkerich/MMS_SDF/sw/mms/dms/FdFtTSB/src/FdFtTSBFDFTableLoadAppl.C:18:
```

The template is this:

```
template <typename T> bool PComp(const T * const & a, const T * const & b)
{
    EcTInt status = a->compareTo(b);
    return ((status == -1) ? true : false);
}
```

the calls I tried in FdFtTSBFDFTableLoadAppl.C were:

```
myIngestedTables.sort(PComp<FoFmVirtualTbl>);   // sorted list
```

or

```
FoFmVirtualTbl sorter;
myIngestedTables.sort(sorter.PComp<FoFmVirtualTbl>);    // sorted lis
```

t

Only when the template was declared in FdFtTSBFDFTableLoadAppl did it compile ok.  So how would I get this to compile if the template is in some others class include?

Comment: This is a new question. Please ask a new question such that people can actually give you an answer and just not mere comments :-).