# How do I sort a set by the dereferenced values?

Tags: c++, set

Suppose I have a set `std::set<*int>` and I want the elements to be sorted by the integer to which they point rather than the pointer type; is there some standard `comp` function I can use from the `std` library? If not, how would I declare such a set?

I'm guessing I would have to do define my own comparison function but how does that look in practice?

Comment: May I ask why you'd have a set of pointers to single ints?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I wouldn't, I actually have a set of pointers to classes with their own `<` operators, but I thought this would be a simplified analogy to my problem.

Comment: Given all that, this is a nearly exact duplicate of the question I just linked.  You'll find its solution works for you too.

Comment: @JohnZwinck that's similar, but it applies to a list which is sorted by `std::sort()`. In my case I need to declare an object of type `std::set<*int,Comp>`, and I don't know how to do that!

Comment: Please don't mark this to close; that question is not related to this one, at least not as far as I can tell. If it is, please tell me why as I would love to know!

Comment: I found a better duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the solution from [Sort a std::list<myclass*> with myclass::operator<(myclass &other)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404160/sort-a-stdlistmyclass-with-myclassoperatormyclass-other) it goes like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct PComp
{
    bool operator ()(const T* a, const T* b) const
    {
       return *a < *b;
    }
};

std::set<int*, PComp<int> > my_set;
```

Comment: Cool, I would never have guess that, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  No need to guess--just think about what the requirements are on the template parameters.  Using a custom comparator like this is fairly commonplace, and this usage is pretty vanilla.  :)

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a `Error: Function template PComp<int> is not a type name` error...

Comment: Yeah, I had posted a function template rather than a functor.  I've fixed it now.

Comment: @JohnZwinck : is it possible to do this inline in an anonymous way?

Comment: It might be "possible," but it's not reasonable.  I've never tried, and I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: @xmoex: [No](http://ideone.com/o1xP1D)

Comment: @xmoex nice solution when you only want to declare it once.